Why is my disk space 100G for Ubuntu 22.04 desktop?
My 100GB SSD is almost full according to "df -h" and I keep getting messages about it. I understand that Ubuntu 22.04 desktop only requires 25GB. I have no video files and only a few photos. I'm using Thunderbird for email with a small number of attached files. Should Ubuntu 22.04 desktop need 100GB, and if not how I find and rectify the problem?
judith@Laptop:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           782M  3.8M  779M   1% /run
/dev/sda7       114G  106G  1.4G  99% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       256M  9.2M  247M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           782M  164K  782M   1% /run/user/1001


The Disk Usage Analyzer (also known as baobab) application is included with Ubuntu Desktop, so you should have that already available. Or you can try What's a command line way to find large files/directories to remove and free up space?

Run sudo du -sh /*|sort -h to find which directory is consuming the most space to investigate what caused the issue.

It looks to me that /var is causing the problem. So I did sudo du -sh /var/|sort -h and it showed the problem was /var/lib. Then "sudo du -sh /var/lib/|sort -h" and the problem was motion, which I used to use for a camera. I then purged motion, with "apt motion" and deleted the /var/lib/motion directory. All Ok now.

Rather then a comment which may not be seen this would be a decent answer.

It sounds like your disk space issue might be due to accumulated files or misconfigured storage. Here’s a short guide to help you identify and fix the problem:
Identify Large Files and Directories: Use du to check the sizes of directories and find what's taking up space.
Check for Large Log Files: Look in the /var/log directory for any large log files and truncate them if necessary.
Clean Package Cache: Run apt-get clean to clear the package cache.
Remove Unnecessary Packages: Use apt-get autoremove to remove unused packages and dependencies.
Check Snap Packages: List installed snap packages and remove old versions.
Check Home Directory: Use du to find large hidden files or directories in your home directory.
Use Disk Usage Analyzer: Open this tool from your applications menu for a graphical view of disk usage.
Use BleachBit: Install and run BleachBit to clean up unnecessary files.
Ubuntu 22.04 desktop typically requires much less space, so these steps should help free up significant disk space.
